# Solving ODE $\dot y = \sqrt{y}$ using Picard and without Picard

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\dot  y = \sqrt{y}, y(0) = 0$. I am asked to solve this differential equation using two methods: with Picard iteration and without using Picard.

**Solving the equation using Picard:**

The integral equation is given by 
$y(t) = \int_{t_0}^t f(s, y(s))ds = \int_{0}^t \sqrt{y(s)}ds$ (since $y_0 = 0$).
So then $y_1 (t) = \int_{0}^t \sqrt{y_0 (s)}ds = \int_{0}^t \sqrt{0}ds = 0$

But this would mean that $y_n (t) = 0$ for all $n \geq 1$. So am I doing something wrong or is the solution 0? And if it is the solution, how do I know it's the only one?

**Solving the equation without using Picard:**

This equation is confusing to me since it's not linear. If I am not mistaken the equation is not exact. Should I try solving it by making it exact by using an integrating factor?

Answer (score 1):

Picard iteration does indeed give you the $y \equiv 0$ solution.

That aside, the solution is not unique, as you can see by applying separation of variables to obtain a solution other than $y \equiv 0$. This example shows why a condition along the lines of the Lipschitz condition in the Picard-Lindelof theorem is necessary for uniqueness.

Comment: Is there a way to use Picard iteration and get the other solution or is 0 the only solution when using Picard?

Do I need to apply separation of variables when trying to solve the equation without using Picard or what do you mean?

Comment: @ABC You can find the zero solution just by substitution without having to do anything with Picard iteration. To find a nonzero solution you can use separation of variables, it's not particularly difficult. The peculiar thing is actually that there are infinitely many solutions, which requires a little bit of thinking to figure out...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find other solutions by selecting a different function $y_0$.  $\dot y(0)=0$ by initial conditions. Assuming a non-zero twice differentiable solution gives $2\dot y\ddot y=\dot y$ with $\dot y(t)\ne 0$ for $t>0$, so $\ddot y(0)=\frac12$ by continuity. Set $y_0(t)=\frac14t^2$, then
$$
y_1(t)=0+\int_0^t\frac{s}2\,ds=\frac14t^2
$$
so that this is already a fixed point.